# sql query to find student having average of 90 from last 2 years?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying this on test table

```sql
create table years (
  yr bigint,
  average decimal(10,2),
  rollno bigint
)
```

i created this table year for storing 2 years like 2020 and 2021
average of marks scored in average

Condition is to find only those students whose avg is above 54 from last 2 years.
data is as follows

```
year    average rollno
2021    55.20   1
2020    55.50   1
2020    54.50   2
2020    55.50   3
2021    55.40   3
```

```
select rollno 
from years
where average > 54
and yr = (YEAR(GETDATE())-1)
and yr = (YEAR(GETDATE())-2)
```

i tried this query but it is not working when i want to specifically find those values where the condition is true.

if i use this query like this

```
select rollno 
from years 
where average > 54
and yr = (YEAR(GETDATE())-1) or yr = (YEAR(GETDATE())-2)
```

it works but doesnt give me the desired result.

result i want is as follows

```
year average rollno
2020  55.50   1
2021  55.20   1
2020  55.50   3
2021  55.40   3
```

but i am getting roll no 2 in the output

Comment: Your first query clearly can't produce any results  as a year cannot be two values at the same time. How does `where average > 55` get you to *"avg is above 90 from last 2 years"*? It looks like you need to aggregate here?

Comment: sorry i missed that detail i want it to be more than 54 because i only want that data which has average above from 54 in both years

Comment: _(Hmmm, yr defined as bigint. Trying to avoid the year-2-billion bug, are we?)_

Comment: Because `and` takes precedence over `or`, you need parentheses around the `or` portion to get your intended results.  Alternately, you can also use the `in` or `between` operators. `where average > 54 and yr IN (YEAR(GETDATE())-1, YEAR(GETDATE())-2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm checking your request after a review in you query, seems there are some parentheses missing in your expression.

Follows the example, based on your query

```
SELECT * FROM years WHERE 
    average > 55 
    and --below the bracket P1
    (--Open P1
        (--Open P2
            yr = year(getdate())-1
        )--Close P2 
        or
        (--Open P3
            yr = year(getdate())-2
        )--Close P3 
    )--Close P1
```

What does it mean in the WHERE clause is the **average > 55**(mandatory) **AND** all what we have inside in the bracket P1 as another condition.

The result

```
year average rollno
2020  55.50   1
2021  55.20   1
2020  55.50   3
2021  55.40   3
```

Best Regards